# How to write into numpy arrays in shared memory with Ray?

Tags: numpy, python-multiprocessing, ray

I am attempting to rewrite Python multiprocessing code using Ray since it appears to be able to abstract shared memory management issues and perform parallel computation faster than straight multiprocessing (based on [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/10x-faster-parallel-python-without-python-multiprocessing-e5017c93cce1)). My goal is to process all timeseries for a lat/lon grid (with both input and output arrays having shape [lat, lon, time]) in parallel without unnecessary copies of the input/output arrays. The idea is to have both input and output arrays in shared memory and multiple processes will read and write into the shared memory arrays so no copies/serialization are needed for each process to access the arrays being worked upon.

My use case is that I have a CPU-heavy function that I want to apply on all 1-D sub-arrays of a 3-D array. I have managed to make this execute much faster using [a home-rolled approach for shared memory objects with multiprocessing](https://github.com/monocongo/climate_indices/blob/master/climate_indices/__main__.py), but the code is much more convoluted/complicated than I'm comfortable with and I'm hoping to simplify it using ray. However I've not yet worked out how to write into shared memory with ray, and without that, I don't see how this can be done. Hopefully someone reading this can suggest a solution.

I have a [Jupyter notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/monocongo/35328ef88af9f4ff8a0eb7e5f6a2854b) with a simple example of what I've tried to get this to work using ray.

Here's the gist:

I initialize my environment for ray and create a function that performs a simple operation on a 1-D slice of a 3-D array and writes the result into an output array, with the expectation that this function can run in parallel and read/write on shared memory representations of my input/output arrays:

```py
import psutil
import numpy as np
import ray

num_cpus = psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)
ray.init(num_cpus=num_cpus, ignore_reinit_error=True)

@ray.remote
def add_average_ray(
        in_ary: np.ndarray,
        out_ary: np.ndarray,
        lat_index: int,
        lon_index: int,
):
    ary = in_ary[lat_index, lon_index]
    out_ary[lat_index, lon_index] = ary + np.mean(ary)
```

Next, I create a function that will loop over a 3-D grid of values and apply the above function to each in parallel using ray:

```py
def compute_with_ray(
        input_array: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    # create an output array that computed values will be written
    output_array = np.full(shape=input_array.shape, fill_value=np.NaN)

    # put the input and output arrays into ray's object store
    in_array_id = ray.put(input_array)
    out_array_id = ray.put(output_array)

    # make a list of futures, one per lat/lon (assuming shape (lat, lon, time))
    futures = []
    for lat_index in range(input_array.shape[0]):
        for lon_index in range(input_array.shape[1]):
            futures.append(add_average_ray.remote(in_array_id, out_array_id, lat_index, lon_index))

    # launch the remote tasks in parallel
    ray.get(futures)

    return output_array
```

Next I make a an input array and exercise the code:

```py
# create an array that can be used to represent a 2x2 cell lat/lon map with 3 times
tst_ary = np.array([[[1, 6, 5], [3, 2, 7]], [[8, 4., 6.], [9, 4, 2]]])

# exercise the ray remote function in parallel
average_added_ray = compute_with_ray(tst_ary)
```

Apparently this is not possible since the arrays that have been added into ray's object store are read-only, and it results in an error:

```
RayTaskError(ValueError): ray_worker (pid=5260, host=skypilot)
  File "<ipython-input-5-0bf9c2bf3f2e>", line 9, in add_average_ray
ValueError: assignment destination is read-only
```

Is there a better way to approach/accomplish this parallel processing on numpy arrays using ray?